# How to delete lines between patterns with custom delimiters

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using `sed (GNU sed) 4.4`

`sed '\@a@d' conf.js` I can delete with a custom delimiter

`sed '/a/,/b/d' conf.js` I can delete an inclusive range with a pattern

`` sed '\@a@,@b@d' conf.js` `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unexpected `,' `` But I cannot delete an inclusive range with a custom delimiter because it doesn't expect the comma

How can I delete lines between two patterns, while using a custom delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape a custom delimiter for each pattern. So this should work:

```
sed '\@a@,\@b@d' conf.js
```

btw this should work on POSIX sed also not just on gnu version.